# How to combine two columns with the same name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame that has two columns named: "cases".
I would like to merge both columns into one, I don't want to perform any calculation.

If cases1 contains "NaN", then cases2 contains data and viceversa.

**cases1 and cases2 cannot both contain data for the same row.**

```
             cases    cases    deaths
2020-01-01   10       NaN      0   
2020-01-02   NaN      2        1
```

**The output should be:**

```
             cases    deaths
2020-01-01   10       0   
2020-01-02   2        1
```

Comment: renaming doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could stat the dataframe over with just `df[['deaths']]` and use `.assign()` to create a new column `cases` that adds the two columns together by column position with `.iloc`:

```
df = df[['deaths']].assign(cases=df.iloc[:,0:2].fillna(0).sum(axis=1))

         deaths cases
2020-01-01    0  10.0
2020-01-02    1  2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
length_row = df.shape[0]
cases = np.empty(length_row)
for row in df.iterrows(): 
    if row[0].isnull() == True:
        cases.append(row[1])
    elif row[1].isnull() == True: 
        cases.append(row[0]) 
df.drop(['cases'] , axis = 1) 
df['cases'] = cases
```

don't know if there is a mistake and also its a bit long, not wise as previous answer though

- get the length of columns
  -create an empty np array
  -iterate over rows by index on 'cases' columns
  -drop the 'cases' columns from dataframe
  -add new array to dataframe.